# Is it possible to install both SQLPS and SqlServer PowerShell module on Windows 10?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

C:>$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()
5.1.18362.145

When I use `Install-Module -Name SqlServer`, it reports:

```
C:>Install-Module -Name SqlServer
PackageManagement\Install-Package : The following commands are already available on this system:'Decode-SqlName,Encode-SqlName,SQLSERVER:,Add-SqlAvailabilityData
base,Add-SqlAvailabilityGroupListenerStaticIp,Add-SqlFirewallRule,Backup-SqlDatabase,ConvertFrom-EncodedSqlName,ConvertTo-EncodedSqlName,Convert-UrnToPath,Disabl
e-SqlAlwaysOn,Enable-SqlAlwaysOn,Get-SqlCredential,Get-SqlDatabase,Get-SqlInstance,Get-SqlSmartAdmin,Invoke-PolicyEvaluation,Invoke-Sqlcmd,Join-SqlAvailabilityGr
```

Yes, those appear to be from the SQLPS module. Is it not possible to have two (2) modules with the same exported names?

**Update:**

Ok, -AllowClobber did avoid the error message. But now I appear to have commands available from both `SqlServer` and `SQLPS`.

C:>get-command *-Sql*

```
CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Alias           Decode-SqlName                                     21.1.18121 SqlServer
Alias           Decode-SqlName                                     14.0       SQLPS
Alias           Encode-SqlName                                     21.1.18121 SqlServer
Alias           Encode-SqlName                                     14.0       SQLPS
Cmdlet          Add-SqlAvailabilityDatabase                        21.1.18121 SqlServer
Cmdlet          Add-SqlAvailabilityDatabase                        14.0       SQLPS
```

But, using `Get-Command` in a different way, only shows commands from the `SqlServer` module.

```
C:>Get-Command Get-Sqli*

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Cmdlet          Get-SqlInstance                                    21.1.18121 SqlServer
Cmdlet          Get-SqlInstance                                    14.0       SQLPS


C:>Get-Command Get-SqlInstance

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Cmdlet          Get-SqlInstance                                    21.1.18121 SqlServer
```

Comment: Why do you want `sqlps` in the first place? It's been superseded by `sqlserver` which is better in all ways.

Comment: I don't want SQLPS. I am trying to move on to SqlServer. I do not yet see a way to uninstall SQLPS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can:

```
Install-Module ... -AllowClobber
```

to override this error, possibly combined with

```
-Scope CurrentUser
```

To only install for a single user.

Or you can [install Powershell Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-windows?view=powershell-6) to create a seperate powershell environment for the other module.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. I have updated the question with the results.